# nohup with nested quotes and subshell

Tags: bash

My goal is to interpolate some output from a pipeline into a string, then append the string to a file:

`echo "some text $(aws ... | tail -1)" >> myfile.txt"`

That works fine. Now I'd like run that in the background and to keep running when I exit the shell:

`nohup bash -c "echo \"some text $(aws ... | tail -1)\" >> myfile.txt" &`

However, this results in only "some text " being appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not invest your time in unreadable quoting. Define a function. Export that function. Run that function in bash.

```
func() {
  echo "some text $(aws ... | tail -1)" >> myfile.txt
}
export -f func
nohup bash -c func &
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't escape the `$` of `$(aws ... | tail -1)`, so the current shell expands it and `bash -c` ends up executing something weird like `echo "some text {"hello": "world"}" >> myfile.txt`

The easy fix is to use single quotes:

```bash
nohup bash -c 'echo "some text $(aws ... | tail -1)" >> myfile.txt' &
```